# Reading Excel file in java doesn't read or count blank cell as null

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm having an issue on my excel reader in java. It doesn't read empty or blank cells and skipping to the next cell that has a value.

example..

```
header1 | header2 | header3 | header4
row1    |         | row3    | row4
row1    | row2    |         | row4
        | row2    | row3    |
```

results:

```
header1 | header2 | header3 | header4
row1    | row3    | row4    | 
row1    | row2    | row4    | 
row2    | row3    |         |
```

expected to happen:

```
header1 | header2 | header3 | header4
row1    | null    | row3    | row4
row1    | row2    | null    | row4
null    | row2    | row3    | null
```

**null** or **" "** (empty string)

Here's my code:

my **readXLSFile** method:

```
private boolean readXLSFile(String batchRunNbr, String filename) throws IOException, ParseException {

        List sheetData = new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            if ((filename.endsWith(".xlsx")) || (filename.endsWith(".XLSX"))) {
                log.info("Reading xlsx file...");
                fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            } else{
                this.errorMessageTxt = this.errorMessageTxt+this.htmlNextLine+
                        "Unable to process the file. Please save the file to the latest Excel *.xlsm or *.xlsx file.";
                return true;
            }


            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            int counter = 0;
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                counter++;
                XSSFRow row = ((XSSFRow) rows.next());
                Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();

                List data = new ArrayList();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();

                    data.add(cell);
                }
                sheetData.add(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.errorMessageTxt = this.errorMessageTxt+this.htmlNextLine+
                    e.getMessage()+this.htmlNextLine+e.getCause();
            return true; //There is an error, return true.
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }

        processExcelSheet(sheetData, batchRunNbr, filename);
```

Here's my **processExcelSheeet** method:

```
private void processExcelSheet(List sheetData, String batchRunNbr, String inputFileName) {
        DateFormat formatter;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        boolean firstTime = true;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
                List list =  (List) sheetData.get(i);
                if (firstTime) {
                    firstTime = false;
                } else {
                    for (int ii = 0; ii < list.size(); ii++) {

                        XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) list.get(ii);
                        switchCase(formatter, ii, cell);
                    }

                    insertToStaging(batchRunNbr, inputFileName);//This method inserts the data to the database based on what it reads above.
                }
                //log.info("COMPLETED!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("loadStagingTable Error:" + e);
            //this.errorMessageTxt = this.errorMessageTxt+this.htmlNextLine+
            //      "Error Loading to KLTL Data Staging. "+e.getMessage()+","+e.getCause();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I suspect that the problem is on the **row.hasNext**?
Please help.. Thank you so much. And if you need more details please do comment it below.

Comment: Have you check the `sheetData`? Based on your result, it should not relevant to `rows.hasNext` or `cells.hasNext`, if it return false, your will not have row 4 in the result set

Comment: Oh.. I tried putting <space> on the empty cells and it reads accordingly. But with empty or blank cells, it skipping the blank cells.. I really don't know what's the issue on my code.. can't find any solutions.

Comment: So have you check the `sheetData` in debugger? or check `data.size()` before `sheetData.add(data)`

Comment: I've printed the `data.size()` and it skips the blanks cells.. :(

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734519/apache-poi-celliterator-skips-blank-cells-but-not-in-first-row

Comment: I tried the code in the link above exactly and I got this error.. `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty cool code so far!

Just a wild guess:  I bet that when you get the "sheet.rowIterator()" you lose your nulls.  This would make sense b/c "Iterators" often ignore empty values.

So... if that's the case... how do you fix it?

Perhaps this will work:

after you define "sheet" try doing something like

```
for(int i = 0; i<sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
  XSSFRow row = ((XSSFRow) sheet.getRow(i));
  for(int j = 0; j<row.getLastCellNum(); j++){
    if(row!=null && row.getCell(j) != null ){
      String val = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
      if(val.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("empty" );
      }
      else{
        System.out.println(val);
      }
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("blank cell");
    }
  }
}
```

;)  happy coding!

Comment: I'm sorry but this code doesn't work.. It returns NullPointer.

Comment: The code works. It only returns NullPointerException, when there is a blank cell. To avoid this, you have to check **row.getCell(j) != null** before getting the value of the cell.

Comment: I came back to this... and cleaned it up for anyone else who looks at this question.  It's checking for NPE and I replaced the ternary operator.